# How to Develop Facebook App When C# SDK Deprecated

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Currently, I have an app and I want to integrate it with Facebook. My App is bases on `C#` and now the `C# SDK` is deprecated. Some requests can't be made by client side requests (extending access token for example), so `Javascript SDK` can't help.

Is there anyone who knows how to integrate a `C#` app with Facebook when `C# SDK` deprecated?

Thanks

Comment: Unless the C# SDK is calling the deprecated REST implementation of the Facebook API there's no reason you can't keep using the C# SDK on your server (presuming it does everything you need it to do). If, however, it is calling the deprecated REST API then you should take a look at the direct URL implementation of most/all Graph API points and call those directly from your own C# code.

Comment: Facebook doesn't have an official C# SDK, but http://csharpsdk.org/ is well maintained and supports the current API

Answer (score 0):

Facebook open graph api's over REST. Event though C# SDK is deprecated, it won't be that tough to write basic http calls with basic http library of C# to make api calls.

With regards to login, you would have to embed an instance of browser, as far as I can remember, C# had msie embed options. Using the browser embed, one would have to capture the access token returned on redirect and use it later for making http calls to REST interfaces of Facebook api's from C#.

Comment: Or they could use the C shark SDK everyone else (in my experience) uses: http://csharpsdk.org/  it's not from Facebook but it's well supported